# finding a word on the following line python

Tags: python, regex, io

I'm searching through a text file for a certain string then looking to find another string following that string, it could be on the next line or further down the document. I currently have

so an example text output would like

```
there is a word1. then there is some more text. 
then we are looking for word2 = apple.
```

i'm looking to return the word 'apple' + word1. However word2= can be on the next line or further down the document. i've managed to do the below but this only works if its on the next line. not if it was on line 3,4, 5 etc. can anyone help?

```
if 'word1' in line and 'word2' not in line:        
    nextLine = next(f)
    pattern = re.match('(?:word2=|word2 =)([a-z0-9_])+',nextLine) 
    if pattern:    
        print('word1', pattern)
```

Comment: It looks as if `with open(filepath, 'r') as f: print(re.findall(r'word2 ?=(\w+)', f.read()))` it will be simpler. Are you looking for a single or multiple matches?

Comment: apologies i should add I need to combine word 1 and pattern together.

Comment: If you need a single match, you might want to try `with open(filepath, 'r') as f: m=re.search(r'word1.*(?:\n.*)*?word2 ?=(\w+)', f.read())` and then `if m: print(m.group(1))`

Comment: need a while loop that scans nextline untill if finds word2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if 'word1' in line and 'word2' not in line: 
while True:       
    nextLine = next(f)
    pattern = re.match('(?:word2=|word2 =)([a-z0-9_])+',nextLine) 
    if pattern:    
        print('word1', pattern)
        break
```

Not sure it will work dont have access to PC let me know, if not working I'll delete it

beware tough:

[Are all infinite loops bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256993/are-all-infinite-loops-bad)

[Is while (true) with break bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390481/is-while-true-with-break-bad-programming-practice)

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right, I made an example for you:

```
string = """

there is a word1. then there is some more text. 
then we are looking for word2 = apple. 


there is a word1. then there is some more text. 
then we are looking for word2 = orange. 



there is a word1. then there is some more text. 
then there is some more text. 
then there is some more text. 
then we are looking for word2= peer. 
"""


import re
result = re.findall(".*?(word1)[\s\S]*?word2 *=.*?([a-z0-9_]+)", string)
print(result)
# should be [('word1', 'apple'), ('word1', 'orange'), ('word1', 'peer')]
```

Note: As I am using the whole string to match, my example may not be suitable for big size file.

Answer (score 0):

You should read your complete file in one string, and then try this. This will capture word1, and whatever equates to word2 using *capturing groups*:

```
(word1)(?:.*[\n\r]?)+word2 ?= ?(\w+)
```

It is not clear from your question whether we should match `word2 = apple` or `word2=apple` (maybe the last time you mentioned `word2=` it was a typo?), so I included the `?` character, which will make the spaces optional.

If you want your answer in the format `apple + word1`, you can do:

```py
print(pattern.group(1) + " + " + pattern.group(2))
```